# A circle divided in 16 segments using CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Any help appreciated.

I need a circle divided into 16 equal segments, 8 in the top hemisphere, 8 in the bottom. Something like an outer circle with an inner circle overlaid, and then wagon wheel spokes to create the segments.

This is how far I've got: https://jsfiddle.net/rxyscrs8/

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

div.field {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.entire-field {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

div.inner-field {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.quarter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.quarter1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
}

.quarter2 {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
}

.quarter3 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}

.quarter4 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="field entire-field">
  <div class="quarter quarter1"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter2"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter3"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter4"></div>
</div>
<div class="field inner-field">
  <div class="quarter quarter1"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter2"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter3"></div>
  <div class="quarter quarter4"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Nice find @MichaelMcMullin I am voting to close this because the linked thread answers this one in principle (even though no. of pieces may be different).

Comment: I gave it a try. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLvqste3/). Reference: [this](http://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish)